# Controller for delete request does not work

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jtwig

I'm really getting started with controllers for my small application, and i have this for now:

```
@RequestMapping("/users/{id}")
public ModelAndView showMemeber(@PathVariable Integer id) {

    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("user/show");

    mav.addObject("title", "Show User");
    mav.addObject("user", userService.findById(id));
    return mav;

}

@RequestMapping(value="/users/{id}", method=RequestMethod.DELETE)
public String deleteMemeber(@PathVariable Integer id) {

    userService.delete(id);

    return "redirect:users";

}
```

the first one, is working properly, but the second doesn't, i have the following view for the first controller:

```
<div class="panel-heading">Personal information</div>
<div class="panel-body">

  <form>

    ...

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete {{ user.username }}?')"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Delete</button>
  </form> 
</div>
```

like you see, i have two buttons here, one for edit the object and one for delete it.
Once deleted it, must redirect to `https://<my domain>/users`.

The problem is, when i click on `Delete` it just *refresh* the page and the object persist on the database, what is wrong here?

- I try send a `DELETE` request like `curl -X "DELETE" http://localhost:8080/my-app/users/18` but this didn't work.
- I try another alternative using [jQuery's ajax-method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#options) (but the same error persist):

  ```
  $.ajax({
      url: '/users/' + someUserId,
      type: 'DELETE',
      success: function(result) {
          // Do something with the result
      }
  });
  ```

Comment: @Tom my mistake, was a previous version. Fixed it.

Comment: Have you tried to use `method=RequestMethod.POST` instead?

Comment: Yes, the behavior is the same.

Comment: did curl return any error? Your code should work fine with curl or AJAX (btu not with html form). Probably error is somewhere else.

Comment: No, any error is returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use ajax to send a DELETE from the web page. The form tag itself only supports POST or GET. In your submit-Handler you have to suppress the default behaviour of the submit button, i.e. the submit of the form via GET or POST (`event.preventDefault()`):

```
$("form").submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
                url: '/users/' + someUserId,
                type: 'DELETE',
                success: function(result) {
                        // Do something with the result
                }
        });
}
```